# Can't get select to work in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to bind a select in Angular and having issues.

Here is HTML

```
<select name="event" ng-model="data.eventID" ng-options="event as event.name for event in events track by event.eventID">
    <option value="0">--- Please select ---</option>
</select>
```

In my controller I initialize "data" before any AJAX calls like this:

$scope.data = {eventID: 0}

Problem #1. data.events gets populated via an AJAX call, but the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<select name="event" ng-model="data.eventID" ng-options="event as event.name for event in events track by event.eventID" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
  <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="2" label="My Event">My Event</option>
</select>
```

Problem #2. A second AXAJ call loads $scope.data, so it becomes $scope.data.eventID = 2, but the select never gets selected to the event with ID 2.

Please note I want to bind to data.eventID, an integer, not an object.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you regenerate your bug in plunker or fiddle ?

Comment: Here is a link http://plnkr.co/edit/Eu3Rhgtkaeo97hFr1uNR to plunkr. Thanks.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define reference of `eventID`

so your select-option should be

```
<select name="event" ng-model="data.eventID" ng-options="event.eventID as event.name for event in events track by event.eventID">
    <option value="0">--- Please select ---</option>
</select>
```

in `select-options` options has define what should display on page and what should be bind on that value once selected.

> so **ng-options = "event.eventID as event.name"**  its means **event.name** is display on page, and for that **event.name -> event.eventID** is pass to controller via **ng-modal**

Update :

based on you plunker

you have `$scope.data = {eventID: 0};` so its always select **please select**

mg-model is two-way bind so, its bind value to selected option.

check this [updated punker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Esb06UvKYdg7Os42p76p?p=preview)

remove `track by event.eventID` you have eventID which provide unique identification to your each `option` tag.

Comment: Thanks but it still didn't work. I changed it to "event.eventID as event.name for event in events track by event.eventID", but the resulting HTML still displays this new option <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>, removes my "Please select" and doesn't switch to the data.eventID that's loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, but in your updated solution, "Please select" disappears. What I am trying to do is pretty boilerplate -- a select control with "Please select" to indicate that no value was selected, options bound to an array, and the value bound to an integer on the scope.